# Developing omni USDT wallet APIs?

Tags: omni

Is it me or does anyone find references to developing Omnicore USDT wallet REST APIs really hard to get?

I'm looking to develop 5 standalone APIs which are:
 1. POST: Send Transaction (signs and return tx hash)
 2. GET: Check Balance
 3. GET: Generate USDT Address & Private Key
 4. GET: Get Tx Hash Details
 5. GET: Get Address Transaction History (array object)

Any procedure to setting up node on AWS to developing the API in NodeJS and connecting NodeJS App with the node is much appreciated!